# What is the recommended way to do mongo map-reduce from within an server http request?

Tags: java, mongodb, mapreduce

I am using the REPLACE output type, meaning the MR result is stored in a collection.

Two http requests do MR simultaneously in different threads - it means I cannot use the same output collection name, so there will be a collection per request, which may result in creation of many MR result collections.

How do you deal with this situation? How do you limit the number of concurrent requests? Do you keep the MR result collections around in case the queries repeat?

In short, I am interested to know how others manage these MR collections (if at all).

I am using mongo java driver (2.7.3) and Restlet (2.0.10)

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't use MR in a loaded system. And if it's not loaded, then there won't be too many collections. Just drop them when you're done with them.

Comment: OK, but how can I avoid MR if it provides the required logic?

Comment: Choose another database, maybe?

Comment: Do you mean another **relational** database?

Comment: Not necessarily relational. You can also use Hadoop-over-MongoDB for your MR jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the results are going to be used more than one time it make sense to create a unique collection for each map-reduce query and whenever you need an answer retrieve the answer from that collection.

Putting up a flag in the server indicating that MR is running might save you from executing simultaneous MR collections. If the MR job is a resource-consuming job, it is a good practice to keep the result of MR somewhere and retrieve it whenever you need it.